# How can I get Final Cut Pro to reload my Motion projects without restarting it?

Tags: video-editing, final-cut-pro

I often switch back and forth between working on a Final Cut project and working on a Motion generator or title I use in that project. If I make changes to the Motion project, I have to restart Final Cut to see those changes reflected in the instances of the generator or title already in the timeline.

Is there a way to get Final Cut to reload the Motion files without restarting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Peeja… the "official" way is to simply **REPLACE** the title or whatever in the timeline with the original from the browser. Select in the timeline, then select in the browser and hit ⌥R to "*Replace from Start*". Or drag from the browser ontop of the timeline instance and select replace from the pop-up.

It's because the edited version only exists in the browser and the instance in the timeline is independent of it.

The UNofficial/*Power User* way … simply **CUT** the title or whatever from the timeline and… **PASTE**. Done.

Cheers.